# Apply rule filling rest of the line with titlesec

Tags: pdftex, titlesec, rules

I want to have a rule in the middle of a line which starts at end of a section and goes all the way to the right margin of a page.

I have seen several posts with solutions and the best one I found is by using this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\centerrule}{\leavevmode\rule[.2em]{\linegoal}{.1em}

\section{section \centerrule}

\end{document}
```

This works fine, but I would like to apply the `\centerrule` with `titlesec` package. Which doesn't work. No matter how I add it, the rule is either in front of the `\section` or under it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Check out leaders and the example on page 225 of the TeXbooku sing {\leaders\hrule}.

Answer (score 1):

This uses leaders.  The tricky bit was figuring out how to raise the `\hrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\leaderfill{\leaders\hrule height4.5pt depth-4pt\hfill\space}

\begin{document}

\section[section]{section \leaderfill}

\section[blindtext]{\sloppy\blindtext \leaderfill}

\end{document}
```